# Sorting an array by date, then alphabetically but keeping the chronology

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I've got two independent sort functions that can sort by date and alphabetically.  However, I need to somehow combine these so that I can sort an array of results by year, then by alphabet within that year.

Does anybody know how this can be achieved?

My current sort functions use uasort and are:

```
function job_year_sort($x, $y)
{
return ($x['YearCompleted'] < $y['YearCompleted']);
 }
```

and

```
function name_sort($x, $y)
{
return strcasecmp($x['ProjectName'], $y['ProjectName']);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this one will sort by year and then by name:

```
function job_year_name_sort($x, $y)
{
    if ( $x['YearCompleted'] == $y['YearCompleted'] ) {
        return strcasecmp($x['ProjectName'], $y['ProjectName']);
    }
    else {
        return $x['YearCompleted'] - $y['YearCompleted'];
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just combine those functions with the wanted logic

```
function year_name_sort($x, $y) {
    if ($x['YearCompleted'] == $y['YearCompleted'])
        return name_sort($x, $y);
    return job_year_sort($x, $y);
}
```